# join multiple queries on one table mysql

Tags: mysql

How can i achieve this in mysql?

Result table

+-----------------+-----------------------+------+
  |st-id            | term                  | score| 
  +-----------------+-----------------------+------+
  | 20001          | 1                      | 5   | 
  | 20002          | 1                      | 6   | 
  | 20001          | 2                      | 6   | 
  | 20002          | 2                      | 4   | 
  | 20003          | 1                      | 7   | 
  | 20003          | 2                      | 9   | 
  
+-----------------+-----------------------+------+--

Result query should be like this

+--------------------------------+
  |st-id            | score->term 1   |        score->term 2
  +-------------------------------+
  | 20001            | 5                              |      6        | 
  | 20002            | 6                              |      4        | 
| 20003            | 7                              |      9        |

+-------------------------------+

Tried

```
(select st-id from result-table where term=1) union (select st-id from result-table where term=2)
```

but it appends the result.

Comment: Look for conditional aggregation

Answer (score 0):

you should use a join (left if the rows don't always match inner if the always match)

```
  select a.st-id, a.score as `score->term 1`,  b.score as `score->term 2` 
  from `result-table` as a  
  left join `result-table` as a   on a.`st-id` = b.`st-id`
  where a.term=1
  and b.term=2
```

or

```
  select a.`st-id`, a.score as `score->term 1`,  b.score as `score->term 2` 
  from `result-table` as a  
  inner join `result-table a`s a   on a.`st-id` = b.`st-id`
  where a.term=1
  and b.term=2
```

and you should not use name as  st-id (the - is an operatore in mysql) ..  if you really need  use backtics